# Solving the integral $\int_{0}^{1} \frac{s \ln(1+s) - t \ln(1+t)}{(s^{2} - t^{2})\sqrt{1-s^{2}}}\,\mathrm{d}s$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, contour-integration, complex-integration

For $t \in [0,1]$, let

$$f(t) = \int_{0}^{1} \frac{s \ln(1+s) - t \ln(1+t)}{(s^{2} - t^{2})\sqrt{1-s^{2}}}\,\mathrm{d}s.$$

Is it possible to evaluate this integral to obtain an explicit expression for $f(t)$? This integral is very similar to the one solved in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4480193/151464), but unfortunately the technique used there of splitting up the integral does not seem to yield obviously tractable integrals (at least for Mathematica!).

### Edit

This integral arose from a research problem in the theory of orthogonal polynomials, which involved finding the equilibrium measure for a particular weight function, $w(x) = \exp(-|x| \ln(1+|x|))$. The extra factor of 1 in the argument of the logarithm ensures smoothness of this weight function near zero.

Here is where I can get to using the method from the linked post.

\begin{align}
    f(t) &= \int_{0}^{1} \dfrac{s \ln(1+s) - t \ln(1+t)}{\sqrt{1-s^{2}}(s^{2} - t^{2})} \, \mathrm{d} s,\\
    &= \underbrace{\int_{0}^{1} \dfrac{s \ln(1+s) - s \ln(1+t)}{\sqrt{1-s^{2}}(s^{2} - t^{2})} \, \mathrm{d} s}_{\equiv I_{1}(t)} + \underbrace{\int_{0}^{1} \dfrac{s \ln(1+t) - t \ln(1+t)}{\sqrt{1-s^{2}}(s^{2} - t^{2})} \, \mathrm{d} s}_{\equiv I_{2}(t)}.
\end{align}
For $I_{2}(t)$, we have
\begin{align}
    I_{2}(t) &= \ln(1+t) \int_{0}^{1} \dfrac{s - t}{\sqrt{1-s^{2}}(s^{2} - t^{2})} \, \mathrm{d} s,\\
    &= \ln(1+t) \int_{0}^{1} \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1-s^{2}}(s + t)} \, \mathrm{d} s,\\
    &= \dfrac{2 \ln(1+t)}{\sqrt{1-t^{2}}} \mathrm{arctanh}{\sqrt{\dfrac{1-t}{1+t}}}.
\end{align}
For $I_{1}(t)$, change variables to $x = \sqrt{1-s^{2}}$, and define $b \equiv \sqrt{1-t^{2}}$. Then we have
\begin{equation}
    I_{1} = \int_{0}^{1} \dfrac{\ln(1+\sqrt{1-x^{2}}) - \ln(1+\sqrt{1-b^{2}})}{b^{2} - x^{2}} \, \mathrm{d} x.
\end{equation}
But whereas in the linked post this integral was solvable by Mathematica, in this case apparently we have no such luck.

Comment: Please show what you tried, recalling https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question, and/or try to improve the quality of the question along the lines in *loc. cit.* - for instance which is the origin, motivation for the question, why is this result important, which is the source... ?!

Comment: @dan_fulea I have edited the post to try to address your concerns. Please let me know if you would like any more information.

Comment: Very similar integral: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4479661/solving-the-integral-int-01-fracs-lns-t-lnts2-t2-sq?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Agreed (I made the linked post!), but unfortunately that method does not seem to straightforwardly generalize, as my edit explains.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Continue with
\begin{align}
    & \int_{0}^{1} \dfrac{s \ln(1+s) - t \ln(1+t)}{\sqrt{1-s^{2}}(s^{2} - t^{2})} \, {d} s\\
   = &\ \underset{=J}{\int_{0}^{1} \dfrac{s \ln(1+s) - s \ln(1+t)}{\sqrt{1-s^{2}}(s^{2} - t^{2})} \, {d} s} + {\int_{0}^{1} \dfrac{s \ln(1+t) - t \ln(1+t)}{\sqrt{1-s^{2}}(s^{2} - t^{2})} \, {d} s}\\
   =&\ J + \frac{2 \ln(1+t)}{\sqrt{1-t^{2}}} \mathrm{arctanh}{\sqrt{\dfrac{1-t}{1+t}}}
\end{align}
and evaluate $J$ below with the variable changes
$ x^2=\frac{1-s}{1+s}$ and $ y^2=\frac{1-t}{1+t}$

\begin{align}
J &= \int_{0}^{1} \frac{s\ln\frac{1+s}{1+t}}{\sqrt{1-s^{2}}(s^{2} - t^{2})} \, {d} s
= \int_{0}^{1} \frac{\ln\frac{1+s}{1+t}}{2\sqrt{1-s^{2}} }\left( \frac 1{s-t} + \frac1{s+t}  \right){d} s\\
&=\frac{1+y^2}2\int_0^1 \frac{\ln\frac{1+y^2}{1+x^2}}{y^2-x^2}
 + \frac{\ln\frac{1+y^2}{1+x^2}}{1-y^2x^2}\ dx\\
\end{align}
where

\begin{align}
\int_0^1 \frac{\ln\frac{1+y^2}{1+x^2}}{y^2-x^2}dx
&= \frac1y \Re\bigg( \text{Li}_2\left(\frac{y+1}{y-i}\right)-\text{Li}_2\left(\frac{y-1}{y+i}\right) \bigg) \\
\int_0^1 \frac{\ln\frac{1+y^2}{1+x^2}}{1-y^2x^2}dx
&= \frac1y \Re\bigg( \text{Li}_2\left(\frac{1+y}{1-iy}\right)-\text{Li}_2\left(\frac{1-y}{1+iy}\right)\bigg)- \frac1y \ln y \ \ln\frac{1-y}{1+y}
\end{align}